# PHP add different values out of array alternately

Tags: php, arrays, alternating

Example :

```
00:00 22-03-2017, John Wilson
08:00 22-03-2017, Gemma Arterton
16:00 22-03-2017, Arnold Plank
00:00 22-03-2017, Timmy Brouwer
08:00 22-03-2017, John Wilson                  <- names repeating
16:00 22-03-2017, Gemma Arterton
```

I am building a shift system that generated a time and date for the next 30 days. I am trying to get different related names to getting echo'd behing the date but so far no luck. 
The names are interactive meaning there could be only 1 aswell as 25 (so to speak).

This is my current call to function code:

```
$month = $shift->date_range(date("Y-m-d"), date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days")), "+" . $shift_facility['facility_shift_duration'] . " hours", "Y/m/d H:i:s", $user_per_facility);
```

And this is my function itself:

```
public function date_range($first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'd/m/Y', $users)
{
    $dates   = array();
    $current = strtotime($first);
    $last    = strtotime($last);
    while ($current <= $last) {
        // Add date and time to array $dates
        $dates[] = date($output_format, $current) . ';' . $users[0]["user_id"];
        //check if we are still in range between the two dates
        $current = strtotime($step, $current);
    }
    return $dates;
}
```

`$users` contains all the user data e.g:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["user_alias"]=>
    string(7) "ND12345"
    ["user_facility"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["user_phone"]=>
    string(5) "12345"
    ["user_name"]=>
    string(9) "Jan steen"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["user_alias"]=>
    string(7) "ND68596"
    ["user_facility"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["user_phone"]=>
    string(11) "31115648597"
    ["user_name"]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
  }
}
```

`$users[0]["user_id"];` 
Only outputs the first name but I need them to alternate (look at the first example).

Does anyone have any idea that could point me in the right direction or help me out a bit?

Thanks in advance ^^

EDIT: More details

My function call is in a foreach:

```
foreach ($facility->getfacilities() as $shift_facility) {

    $user_per_facility = $user->getusersbyFacilityId($shift_facility['facility_id']);

    if (isset($user_per_facility[0]["user_id"])) {
        //if shift count > dan db results generate new day
        $month = $shift->date_range(date("Y-m-d"), date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days")),
            "+" . $shift_facility['facility_shift_duration'] . " hours", "Y/m/d H:i:s", $user_per_facility);

    }

}
```

Comment: Got it... is your `date_range` method called from within a loop?

Comment: @mwieczorek Yeah , i'll add it in the post, I cant format code in this post very well ^^

Comment: Can you post that code above into your question, formatted?

Comment: @mwieczorek done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case people stumble on the same issue:

I fixed this issue by creating an variable `$i` and if it exceeded the size of var `$users` had it set back to value 0.
(aswell as counting up for each succesfull row)

```
$i = 0;
 if ($i > count($users)-1) {
            $i = 0;
        }
        // Add date and time to array $dates
        $dates[] = date($output_format, $current) . ';' . $users[$i]["user_id"];

        //check if we are still in range between the two dates
        $current = strtotime($step, $current);
        $i++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're sending an entire array of `$users` to the `date_range()` method, where you should only be sending one entity of that array (e.g. a single user) to that method.

You're calling `$users[0]` from within that method, which will always reference the first (zeroth) element from that array, not the specific one you're looking for.

The issue starts from this block:

```
if (isset($user_per_facility[0]["user_id"])) {
    //if shift count > dan db results generate new day
    $month = $shift->date_range(date("Y-m-d"), date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days")),
        "+" . $shift_facility['facility_shift_duration'] . " hours", "Y/m/d H:i:s", $user_per_facility);

}
```

That only checks if the `user_id` is set in the first array element. You need to loop through the users array as well:

```
foreach ($facility->getfacilities() as $shift_facility) {
    $user_per_facility = $user->getusersbyFacilityId($shift_facility['facility_id']);

    // Make sure $users_per_facility can be iterated over
    if (count($users_per_facility) > 0 && is_array($users_per_facility))
        foreach ($users_per_facility as $u) {
            if (isset($u["user_id"])) {
                //if shift count > dan db results generate new day
                $month = $shift->date_range(date("Y-m-d"), date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days")),
                    "+" . $shift_facility['facility_shift_duration'] . " hours", "Y/m/d H:i:s", $u);

            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Then modify your `date_range()` method to only take a single user element, not the entire array. For clarification, I changed `$users` to `$user` because there is only one "user" being sent to that method:

```
public function date_range($first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'd/m/Y', $user) {
    $dates   = array();
    $current = strtotime($first);
    $last    = strtotime($last);
    while ($current <= $last) {
        // Add date and time to array $dates
        $dates[] = date($output_format, $current) . ';' . $user["user_id"];
        //check if we are still in range between the two dates
        $current = strtotime($step, $current);
    }
    return $dates;
}
```

I would also suggest that you re-order the argument list for the `date_range` method. I'd suggest putting `$user` first:

```
public function date_range($user, $first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'd/m/Y')
```

Also, it's good convention to give your methods (functions) names with a **verb**, since they "do" something. In this case, `make_date_range`. Since I can see this is in a class (having the `public` keyword), it's a good habit to make your method names `camelCase`, e.g. `makeDateRange()`, while keeping your variables with underscores. Not required by any means, but it's good practice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesnt this output : `00:00 22-03-2017, [same_name], 08:00 22-03-2017 [same_name]` multiple times instead of `00:00 22-03-2017 [name_1], 08:00 22-03-2017 [name_2]`?

Comment: This would print each user from each "facility". We're passing only ONE  user to the date_range.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getusersbyFacilityId() on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\Consignatie\index.php:41 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Consignatie\index.php on line 41

Comment: Oops. Scoping issue, didn't see the $user-> object being referenced, see my changes, I changed $user to $u in the inner foreach loop

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out btw, but this outputs an array with dates for each name . What i am trying to achieve is one array per facility with different names behind the date's. Like the first example in my question. Think of it like an work schedule person A has to work from time A - B at date 1 and person B has to work from B-C at date 1 and person A has to work again from A-B at date 2.

Tho this could be more people working at different hours (not specificly Always time A-B for person A)

Comment: I fixed the issue, Thanks for trying to help me out mate ^^ I owe you one.